# How to pull data from Sharepoint List

Tags: java, .net, sharepoint, wsdl, integration

I have a list in sharepoint server, how can I pull the data from it using SOAP connection and GetListItems method.

http://***.***.*:9595/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possibly a good starting point http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/03/10/calling-sharepoint-lists-web-service-using-wcf.aspx

Comment: Using which language java or .Net ?